# How can I set the JDK NetBeans runs on?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I have the older NetBeans 6.7, NetBeans 6.9, and NetBeans 7.0, which used to run on jdk1.6.0_21 and jdk1.6.0_25. Now I've removed those JDKs and only have jdk1.6.0_26 and jdk1.7.0 left, but I still want to keep the older versions of NetBeans, but now when I run them, I get this message:

> "Cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 
> Do you want to try to use default version?"

I tried to find where it's looking for the "jdk1.6.0_25", and updated a few configuration files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.7" and "C:\Users\USER.nbi\registry.xml", and yet the message keeps coming. Where and what do I need to change to point it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`?

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Thanks to [Kasun Gajasinghe's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-can-i-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on/6951067#6951067), I found the solution in the "suggested" link. Update the following file (replace **7.x** with your NetBeans version):

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.x\etc\netbeans.conf
```

Change the following line to point it where your Java installation is:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7xxxxx"
```

You may need administrator privileges to edit `netbeans.conf`.

Comment: I ran into this problem after replacing OpenJDK with Oracle's Java for Android development on Ubuntu 13.04. The file is in 
`/usr/local/netbeans-7.3/etc/netbeans.conf` 

And my adjusted line looks like this:
`netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21"`

Comment: This has always worked for me but somehow recently it did not and I couldn't track down any explanation other than yours.  By accident I thought to edit the file as Administrator and that did have the right effect.  Somehow Windows 7 Enterprise and Windows 8 Pro are maintaining two versions of this file for me (see http://superuser.com/q/680110/47313)

Comment: @asciimo For completion, you can even customize the properties on a per-user basis by writing a `netbeans.conf` under `~/.netbeans/version/etc` that overrides the `/usr/local...` properties file. (I assume `/usr/local/netbeans-7.3/etc` is your distro installation folder--I'm developing with a manual installed version in customized folder and cannot be 100% sure--.)

Comment: NB: As of Netbeans 8 there is also a netbeans.conf in `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\etc\netbeans.conf`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon In my case the file you mentioned and the etc dir didn't exist, but netbeans_jdkhome worked, when I created the file manually. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly with current NetBeans 8.0.1!

Comment: As noted in the comments in that file, you can comment out the line to let the launcher decide which version to use. This normally manages to automatically pick the most recent version.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Not for me there isn't.

Comment: Heed the suggestion that Administrator privileges are needed to edit netbeans.conf, at least under Windows 7.  I tried editing the file _without_ Administrator privileges and while it appeared to work, apparently Windows actually saved the updated file as a separate copy that was only visible to me via Windows Explorer.  When NetBeans ran, it read the _original_ file, which still referenced the old JDK.  What bizarre and confusing behavior on the part of Windows.

Comment: solution still valid for netbeans 8.1 i've mistakenly pointed jdk home to /usr during the installation changed the pointed file part to /usr/lib/jvm/java on my fedora box and it has java capabilities again!

Answer (score 70):

Go to Tools* → *Java Platforms*. There, click on *Add Platform* and point it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`. You can either set the another JDK version or remove existing versions.

Another solution [suggested](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome) on the Oracle ([Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems)) site is,

```
netbeans.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\jdk1.6.0_20"
```

I tried this on 6.9.1. You may change the JDK per project as well. You need to set the available JDKs via the *Java Platforms* dialog. Then, go to *Run* → *Set Project Configuration* → *Customize*.
After that, in the opened dialog box, go to menu *Build* → *Compile*. Set the version.

Comment: There is no `Java Platforms` menu item in Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 33):

For those not using Windows, the file to change is `netbeans-8.0/etc/netbeans.conf`.

And the line(s) to change is:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Comment out the old value and insert the new value.

Comment: This worked for me using Ubuntu 18.04 and NetBeans IDE 8.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As a further useful solution for those of you on Windows 7 and above - if you use

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java"
mklink /D jdk8 jdk1.8.0_25
```

you get a *[symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)* folder that can be adjusted whenever a new JDK comes out.

All you need to do then is set your

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8"
```

(in both locations for NetBeans 8) and you never have to edit the configuration again. Just tweak the symlink each time your JDK is updated.

Answer (score 6):

I had this message too because today I decided to relocate my different JDK in the same directory. I have decided to uninstall all through the program manager of Windows. After that, of course I had the message below.

> "Cannot locate java installation in specified jdkhome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60. Do you want to try to use the default version?"

A new install of the JDK does not resolve the problem. OK, you can configure that in menu *Tools* → *Java platforms*, but in my case I had to fix my *netbeans.conf* file.

I had the line below:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60"
```

And I replaced it by:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\devtools\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
```

Comment: You probably want to just comment out that line.  In that case, Netbeans will search and find the latest version on startup.

Answer (score 5):

It does not exactly answer your question, but to get around the problem,

1. you can either create a .cmd file with following content:

   `start netbeans --jdkhome c:\path\to\jdk`
2. or in the shortcut of Netbeans set the above option.

Answer (score 4):

Where you already have a project in NetBeans and you wish to change the compiler (e.g. from  1.7 to 1.) then you would need to also change the Java source compiler for that project.

Right-click on the project and choose *Properties* as outlined below:

[image: Java Project Properties]

Then check that the project has the necessary source circled below:

[image: Project Source Compiler]

Then check that the Java compiler is correct for the project:

[image]

Comment: Excellent [red circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)!

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers have described how to explicitly specify the location of the Java platform, which is fine if you really want to use a specific version of Java.  However, if you just want to use the most up-to-date version of the JDK, and you have that installed in a "normal" place for your operating system, then the best solution is to *not* specify a JDK location.  Instead, let the NetBeans launcher search for the JDK every time you start it up.

To do this, do not specify jdkhome on the command line, and comment out the line setting netbeans_jdkhome variable in any *netbeans.conf* files.  (See other answers for where to look for these files.)

If you do this, when you install a new version of Java, your NetBeans installation will automagically use it.  In most cases, that's probably exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, open `cmd`.

Go to the directory where your NetBeans file downloaded.

Then run the below command. The JDK path may be different from the path I mentioned.

```
netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1"
```

Comment: Use --jdkhome and not --javahome instead and link leads to spam page.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Netbeans IDE 17 go to `Tools -> Java Platforms`:
[image]

Then in the `Java Platform Manager` click on `Add Platform...`:
[image]

Then go through the next menu options and select the jdk version you downloaded that you want to add to netbeans, then click on `Finish`, now you'll see a new platform listed with the jdk you just added:
[image]

Now go to `Tools -> Options` then go to the `Java -> Maven` tab and for the `Default JDK` option you can now select the new jdk you added above:

[image]

Now when you compile your application on Netbeans you can see the Java version it is using:

[image]