# Grizzly - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName

Tags: java, web-services, soap, grizzly

I have a wsdl file for the Web service. I want to test the interaction between the client and the server. To do this, I run the mock server with embedded grizzly.

The question about of implementing mock server. I generated an interface from wsdl (and xsd) using the wsimport and wrote implementation. When run on the grizzly, I get the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.server.ServerRtException: [failed to localize] cannot.load.wsdl(META-INF/wsdl/test.wsdl)
```

I run a web service with this code:

```
 HttpHandler httpHandler = new JaxwsHandler(new TestImpl());
 server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(httpHandler, "/test");
```

The problem is that Grizzly can not find wsdl and xsd files. In embedded glassfish its work.

#### EDIT1

I change wsdlLocation to "test.wsdl" and its work. But now grizzly say:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

#### EDIT2

If use JDK1.7 it works. But I need a JDK 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, we had to use endorsed mechanism. [Documentation](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/examples/using-jaxws22-on-jdk6.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're seeing that error.  I can run the Grizzly jaxws example and obtain the wsdl using either 1.6 or 1.7.

I would recommend reviewing the source[1](http://java.net/projects/grizzly/sources/git/content/samples/http-jaxws-samples/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/samples/jaxws/Server.java?rev=6f36787e9604965a29b1a95fd3421fae20166a76) of the example and compare to what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm change the jdk6 to jdk7 and works fine! Don't forget to change the JAVA_HOME and the default JDK of Netbeans as related here: [How to set the JDK Netbeans runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-point-netbeans-to-new-jdk)

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Grizzly expects a JAX-WS 2.2 API while JDK 1.6 ships with JAX-WS 2.1. As others mentioned, some of these files need to be installed into an endorsed directory. You can download the required files [here](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.10/) or take them from your Grizzly installation. The download includes an Ant build file that provides a build target to install the files into the JDK endorsed directory. You can run it with `ant install-api`. If you cannot run Ant, you may install them manually:

```
cp lib/jaxb-api.jar $JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed
cp lib/jaxws-api.jar $JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed
```

Do not install other files from the JAX-WS distribution into the endorsed directory unless you want to create some really difficult to debug bugs for yourself.

I am suggesting to use the endorsed directory in $JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed because that will work with most tools and applications without any additional changes. Others already suggested more targeted changes, such as setting an endorsed directory during a Maven build or copying the files into a Tomcat endorsed directory. All these approaches are fine as long as you can make sure that your code is picking up the right endorsed directory.

Answer (score 0):

create a folder called endorsed and put these jar files in it 
1.jaxb-api-2.2.jar
2.jaxws-api.jar
put the folder in tomcat server as
C:\tomcat-7.50\< created folder>
and run it will works

Answer (score 0):

Changing JDK from 1.6 to 1.7 worked for me.