# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, web-services, exception, netbeans, jax-ws

Created a web service which returns a list of custom objects in netbeans 7.3, using jax-ws 2.2, tomcat-6.0, jdk 1.6 - 
On calling this service from client is gives this exception -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1213)
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:943)
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:711)
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:472)
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:314)
com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:130)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.buildRuntimeModel(WSServiceDelegate.java:782)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:789)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:765)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:363)
com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:345)
javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
service.StockDao_Service.getStockDaoPort(StockDao_Service.java:56)
org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp._jspService(newjsp_jsp.java:72)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

After doing some research on net found I have to create endorsed folder in tomcat/lib and copy web service jars in %CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed folder. After setting global var CATALINA_HOME as tomcat root directory on win-7 and setting this path in catalina home.prperties I am still getting this error. I am working on Hadoop so I have copied all hadoop and jax-ws jars at both places tomcat-6.0/lib and tomcat-6.0/lib/endorsed folder.

Comment: try it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356479/grizzly-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-xml-ws-webfault-messagename