# Calling a JAX-WS RI 2.2 service from Tomcat6 with java6

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws

I am trying to access a JAX-WS 2.2 service from Tomcat6 with Java6. For what I have researched there is a problem with this, as Java tries to use first some of its default javax.xml.ws libraries which doesn't have the `WebFault.messageName` method. So it fails with this error:

```
GRAVE: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1162)
...
```

The solution seems to be creating an "endorsed" directory in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ (or in TOMCAT_HOME) and putting there the required libraries.

However, some people say the library needed is `webservices-api.jar`, for example, here (#Issue 3):

https://www.fromdev.com/2010/01/trying-to-run-jax-ws-sample-application.html

And other people talk about `jaxb-api-2.2.jar` and `jaxws-api.jar`, for example here:

[Grizzly - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356479/grizzly-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-xml-ws-webfault-messagename)

I have downloaded all three of them and placed them in both directories (inside JAVA_HOME and TOMCAT_HOME).

My problems:

· I have no issues accessing this service from a standalone java6 application, both from Netbeans or running the .jar from command-line, it fails only from Tomcat. So I am not sure if the stated above is the cause of my problems. Because, shouldn't it also fail from command line?

· I am not being able to test the above solutions, because Tomcat does not seem to know the "endorsed" directory. When I run this in the standalone application:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));
```

It prints:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/endorsed
```

However, Tomcat prints a blank line.

I have tried to modify `tomcat6.conf`, with this (and restarting, of course):

JAVA_OPTS="**-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed** -Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

But it still doesn't seem to know that property.

So, how can I tell Tomcat where the endorsed directory is located? Do you think that my problem can be another than the stated, as it works from a standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution:

> *Do you think that my problem can be another than the stated, as it works from a standalone application?*

No, that was exactly the problem.

> *how can I tell Tomcat where the endorsed directory is located?*

It seems that setting this option in tomcat6.conf:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed
```

is not enough. It is required to create a variable called JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS. So these two lines are needed in tomcat6.conf:

```
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS="/usr/share/tomcat6/endorsed"
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS [-Djava....]"
```

Not really well documented issue, I think.