# Netbeans - change the JDK platform

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-7

I used the Netbeans "7.3.1". Previously I used the JDK "1.7.0_25". Now I installed the new jdk(1.7.0_45) and changed the path settings in environmental variables also. But Netbeans still pointing to the JDK "1.7.0_25". For changing this , I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-point-netbeans-to-new-jdk) as reference. 
But I am unable to save that file. Plz anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank pointed out in his provided answer that you are linking:

> You may need Administrator privileges to edit netbeans.conf

Comment: I have it but still i am unable to save it. Is any other ways to do it?

Comment: Ok, what error message do you get when you try to save the file? What OS are you on? To which user does the file belong? Are you sure you have admin priviliges (under Windows a admin is not always really a admin who can do everything)

Answer (score 0):

on windows 7 with user picary you can try this:
put the etc/netbeans.conf file into C:\Users\PICARY\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3 and C:\Users\PICARY\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\7.3
Open that config file and change your java installation to netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

Answer (score 0):

To change the JDK trajectory in netbeans you must do the following.

You enter the directory where netbeans is installed. For example,
`C: \ Program Files \ NetBeans-xx \ netbeans \ etc` and in the file

> netbeans.conf

update the line
`netbeans_jdkhome` = **"insert the jdk path"**