# netbeans won't start after changing netbeans.conf

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I am working with netbeans on windows8. I have decided to change my jdk. So I Uninstalled jdk 7 and installed jdk 8 properly. Then according to this link:
[How to set the JDK Netbeans runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on)
I changed netbeans.conf.

But now I can't make netbeans start.

What should I do?

and here's my `netbeans.conf` after changing:

```
netbeans_default_userdir="${DEFAULT_USERDIR_ROOT}/7.2"
netbeans_default_cachedir="${DEFAULT_CACHEDIR_ROOT}/7.2"

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"
```

Comment: What change did you make?

Comment: netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25" -> netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05"

Comment: Switch netbeans_jdkhome back to 1.7.0_25 and try to start NB.

Comment: Is Java 8 correctly installed? Is there a bin folder in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05" with java.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that NetBeans 7.2 doesn't work with Java 8 as it was only tested with Java 6 and 7 when it was released. Update to newer version (8.0.1 at the moment).

Also you may want to inspect log file to see if there is some hint (`var/log/messages.log` in userdir).