# Can't find symbol error while doing System.out.println()

Tags: java, netbeans

Getting: **can't find symbol** whenever I typed `System.out.println();`

**What, I have tried:**

Deleted and reinstalled netbeans a couple times to no avail. Tried deleting the cache and now the line of code won't throw error if it is written in the main method of the main class, otherwise, it throws error still.

P.S. **IDE:** netbeans 8.1 **OS:** Windows 7.

Comment: Formatted text and separated what user tried

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any additional info other than your OS and IDE might I suggest:

It doesn't look like netbeans comes with a JDK from this page:
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/81/install.html

Verify that you have the latest release of the Java JDK from this page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Make sure that netbeans is pointed to the correct JDK:
[How to set the JDK Netbeans runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on)

If you can provide some sample code to demonstrate the situation in which your issue is occurring, someone may be able to provide more concise assistance.