# Netbans fails to start after splash screen in ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java

Netbeans 8.1 fails to start after splash screen when opened directly by clicking on application icon.
Although it runs when used called through console using following command --

```
./bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

It works perfectly when opened with above command.
Tried searching, found a helpful answer --

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951067/2359028

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is caused when any project dependency is missing. Suppose you have a `java` project setup in Netbeans, but Netbeans couldn't find `jdk` package. So it fails to load.

But when you use console to load the application, you pass the `jdk` location to application to load its dependency, so it worked perfectly.

The problem can be solved by modifying Netbeans configuration file. Go to installation location of Netbeans (in my case - `usr/local/netbeans-8.1`), then inside `/etc` folder edit `netbeans.conf` file and set the location of your jdk installation in `netbeans_jdkhome` variable

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

That's it. Start your Netebeans application by clicking on your application icon.

You can get list of locations for java installation using following command -

```
update-alternatives --config java
```