# Netbeans Platform 8.1 Project gives "JVM Creation Failed"

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, netbeans-platform

Please note is issue is not the same as the Netbeans IDE giving a "JVM Creation Failed." This error occurs when I use Netbeans 8.1 IDE to start my Netbeans 8.1 Platform project.

When I click run on my project, I get the following pop-up message:
[Cannot locate java installation pop-up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3GPv.png)

After clicking 'Yes' on the pop-up, I immediately get a message saying "JVM creation failed". Here is the image of the error: [JVM creation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5kyN.png)

I've tried reinstalling Netbeans, both x86 nd x64. I've also tried changing the path of the JDK on the project. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the first picture it seems that you somehow specified an invalid JDK location for NB to use on startup. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on) provides detailed info on how you can check and change the startup JDK.

Comment: Thank you, but I needed the project to see the JDK, and the IDE already sees it (conf file already configured correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had to configure the project to use the JDK I wanted it to use. I thought this was already set, but it wasn't. I right-clicked the project ->Properties->Libraries-> Select JDK in "Java Platform" combo box. It was blank before I specified it. I just used the default.