# Tomcat fails to start in Netbeans: JRE_HOME not defined, although it is and working

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have installed Tomcat in zip form, both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environmental variables are set and when I start Tomcat from cmd it is working perfectly. But, if I want to start it from Netbeans it fails constantly.

Here is the log:

```
03-Feb-2017 08:34:20.418 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()

03-Feb-2017 08:34:20.424 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()

03-Feb-2017 09:00:03.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()

03-Feb-2017 09:00:03.968 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()

03-Feb-2017 11:03:04.721 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()

03-Feb-2017 11:03:04.722 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

And here is the error:
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

JRE_HOME is set and program works, if I do echo `%JRE_HOME%` I get the right path. 2 hours reading and trying everything possible did not give result.
Any proposals?

Comment: run netbeans as admin

Comment: did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6958342/5558072

Comment: Just started it as an administrator, it worked! Now it says that my port is busy, although it is not. Thanks for help! Any proposals for this current problem?