# NetBeans can't find JDK 10 I installed

Tags: java, netbeans

I am reading the JavaEE first cup, and I needs JDK8+, my version is older, so I upgraded my java, Configure the System Path, Install so on, I successfully run `java -version` in command prompt and it recognizes me that I've installed successfully, but when I start my NetBeans, It can't find Java! Not only that, but also my Eclipse neon can't find java! I check the eclipse.ini, maybe it just need a JDK 8. So I just wonder, how can I make my NetBeans found my Java?

Comment: Oh,My jDK version log:java version "10" 2018-03-20

Comment: i had simular with netbeans 8.2 try installing netbeans dev edition

Comment: I try to fix it,However,JDK 10 hasn't been supported by NetBeans.So just degrading your JDK to 1.8 144+.

Comment: yeah but i am using this version with jdk 10
[netbeans dev ed](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/2018-03-28_00-02-34/)

Comment: You have this issue back to front. It is Netbeans that can't find Java, not the other way around. You need to adjust the path to the Java binary somewhere in the Netbeans configuration files. Ditto for Eclipse.

Comment: To set JDK path in Netbeasn as suggested by @EJP refer this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6950960/5180017)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to netbeans,so I resort to configuration in eclipse.ini,I try to add “--ALL"like script,I doesn't work anyway!Thank to my patience,I notice some jdk1.8required
property,I am completely rush to my deadline,so I  avoid to this problem,and got 1.8，but thanks a lot if you recommend eclipse IDE lastest version which can work well  with JDK 10 without any modification in ini file!