# apache netbeans 11.3 C++ plugin timeout, unable to install

Tags: c++, netbeans

Im moving to Apache Netbeans 11.3 and trying to install the C++ plugin on Windows 10, got the follow repos

http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz

http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

but everytime it hits the 99% it simply give me a timeout error when unpacking org-netbeans-modules-cnd-dwarfdiscovery.nbm

**The Plugin Installer found problem timeout of loading C/C++ Repository[org.netbeans.modules.cnd.repository/1.32.6.1] while install the following plugins:**

already try versions 10, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, got the same issue, i even got rid of the windows firewall to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the Java version
For me, I have Java version 14
So this version has no program
unpack200.exe

Problem was solved by copying the unpack200.exe file from Java version 1.8 to the bin folder in java 14

Comment: This is a bad approach which is unnecessary, unwise and unsupported. When [functionality has been deliberately removed from Java](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/367) it is never a good idea just to manually restore that missing functionality. It was removed for a reason. See [Couldn't install netbeans 11.3 with Java 14 due to Error: “Unsupported JVM version”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922968/2985643) for proper alternative approaches.

Comment: Simply because version 11.3 of NetBeans Depends on the unpack200  to decompress the plugins

Comment: This didn't work for me, but temporarily downgrading the java home to a java 8 version (`netbeans_jdkhome=/path/to/java` in `/path/to/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf`) did.

Comment: Temporarly downgrading is the method of choice! Especially if you want to install the C/C++ plugin, which definitely needs the `unpack200` otherwise it will give the timeout error. So I started netbeans with java 11 by the `--jdkhome` option, installed the plugin via 'Tools' 'Plugin' successfully and restarted with java 14. Worked!

Comment: @skomisa Uninstalling NetBeans is not a proper alternative.

Comment: @IanBoyd Uninstalling NetBeans is the only _"proper alternative"_ if you are doing a new install of NetBeans, and the installation has failed due to the OP's problem. You can then cleanly install using an older JDK, or directly download/unzip the NetBeans binary which bypasses the installer. And if you are upgrading NetBeans then _"Temporarily downgrading is the method of choice"_, as mentioned in Erich's comment above. In neither scenario is making changes to Java libraries a _"proper alternative"_; it's a hack. Regardless the issue no longer exists in more recent versions of NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

copy and paste pack200, unpack200 and unpack.dil from bin of jdk13 into the bin of jdk14. This worked for me and I assure you that it will work for you. I did this with openjdk.