# NetBeans IDE 8.2 failed to download plugin

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-8.2

I tried to download Java EE Base Plugin in my NetBeans 8.2. But it could not finish and below warning is displayed.
Edit : I wanted to install the plugin because I wanna create new project, Web Application

```
Networking problem in http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/files/nbms/z8930_dukewizard-2.1.nbm

Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic. Your cache may be out of date. Please click Check for Updates to refresh content.
```

What I have tried:

1. Turn off windows firewall
2. Turn proxy setting to no proxy

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you

Comment: I don't think you will be able to download any NetBeans plugins that start with **http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/....**. NetBeans 8.2 is a very old release that was created by Oracle, but NetBeans is now supported by Apache, and they explicitly do not support version 8.2. Also, the name of the plugin in your question (_z8930_dukewizard-2.1.nbm_) doesn't look correct for Java EE. Can you update your question to link to what made you attempt to install that plugin?

Comment: Ty for the info. Plus, I already edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try an alternative update center which one of the Netbeans community members set up: http://plugins.archive.librebeans.org/catalogue/8.2/catalog.xml

A list of update centers for other (older) versions can be found in the Netbeans Confluence: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Where+to+download+plugins+for+NetBeans+10.0+and+earlier