# Netbeans IDE cannot access java.lang

Tags: java, netbeans

Downloaded Netbeans IDE 13 and I get this error right after I complete creating a class in the IDE.
The problem is I used to have netbeans 12.6 last year which worked perfectly fine, my course requires me to use netbeans 13 along with java 17. I am assuming something happened while deleting some files last time along with 12.6.

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you

[image]

I tried deleting and install java as well as netbeans, but it wont change anything.

Comment: You might have to manually set the path to your jdk installation in the Netbeans settings or directly in its configuration file. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958342/16628567